# Fundamental complex number formula kept secret?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, geometric-algebras

I recently started self-studying of complex analysis.
I checked several popular online courses, and all of them, of course, start with the basic definitions:

- real and imaginary parts of a complex number,
- complex conjugation and the module of a complex number,
- addition and multiplication of complex numbers.

This set of definitions is usually followed by a set of properties that includes the connection with *vectors*.

The connection with *vectors* is trivial for all the terms, except for the *multiplication*.
I was surprised I was not able to find it in those courses.
Furthermore, for some time I could not find it anywhere, including available AIs.

But the formula is known (e.g. Tristan Needham "Visual Complex Analysis", 2023):

$$\tag{1}zw = (\bar{z}w) + i[\bar{z}w]$$

where $\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$,
$(xy) = Re(x)Re(y) + Im(x)Im(y)$ is the vector dot product,
$[xy] = \begin{vmatrix} Re(x) & Im(x) \\\ Re(y)&Im(y) \end{vmatrix}$ is the vector cross product.

We can also use the fact that $[xy] = (xy^{\perp})$,
where $\begin{pmatrix} a \\\ b \end{pmatrix}^{\perp} = \begin{pmatrix} b \\\ -a \end{pmatrix}$ is a vector orthogonal to $\begin{pmatrix} a \\\ b \end{pmatrix}$:

$$\tag{2}zw = (\bar{z}w) + i(\bar{z}w^{\perp})$$

In this form we can find it in the proof of the Cauchy's integral theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Relation_of_complex_line_integral_and_line_integral_of_vector_field

The formula looks beautiful and deep to me, so I cannot understand why it is not mentioned in the first chapter of every course on complex numbers.

What is the reason of not including the formula into the basis of the complex numbers theory?
Is it considered not fundamental enough?
Or, maybe, I am taking wrong courses?
Are there other interesting applications of the formula?

Comment: Found it in Tristan Needham "Visual Complex Analysis", 2023 (first edition published in 1997). Here is also a demo published in 2011: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DotAndCrossProductsRelatedToComplexMultiplication/. Maybe, I am taking wrong courses. Please let me know if I better delete the question.

Comment: Bless your heart and your self confidence.

Comment: Please don't put AI/LLM output in your question. It is against the policies of the site (although it's not stated clearly enough, so you can't be blamed for not knowing).

Comment: @JonathanZ Removed. Thank you.

Comment: The formula is probably not included because it's more complicated than the formula $(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$, which itself follows from more fundamental stuff like the distributive law and $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Also, the geometric meaning of multiplication can be understood more directly by writing the complex numbers in polar form, which is taught in introductory courses.

Comment: But this formula is interesting! It reminds me of the way [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) multiplication can be expressed using dot products and cross products - maybe there's a connection.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The question is about the connection between complex numbers and vectors. IMHO, if you said "vector" in one place you must explain all other places as well.

Comment: @Karl The polar form does not explain the connection between complex numbers and vectors. It looks like the Geometric Algebra does.

Comment: @Aruralreader Now I am confident this is my best question on the website so far.

Comment: "The question is about the connection between complex numbers and vectors." No, it isn't; the question is, and I quote, "What is the reason of not including the formula into the basis of the complex numbers theory?" And that's the question I answered. No vectors there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please help me to understand it. You do not see the vector operations in "the formula" you refer to? Maybe, I could formulate my question better if I saw the disconnection.

Comment: Here are the questions you ask: "Fundamental complex number formula kept secret?" "The formula looks beautiful and deep to me, so I cannot understand why it is not mentioned in the first chapter of every course on complex numbers." "What is the reason of not including the formula into the basis of the complex numbers theory?" I suggest that the reason the formula is "secret", "not mentioned", "not included" is precisely because it drags in vector operations when it's so easy to define multiplication without ever mentioning vectors.

Comment: @GerryMyerson And I replied that if you drag vector operation for addition then you must drug vector operation for multiplication as well, or to not mention that a complex number is a vector. Besides, my original question suggested that using the formula makes the proof of the Cauchy's integral theorem a bit easier. This is why, IMHO, we better show it in the courses.

Comment: Ah, so that's what you meant by *if you said "vector" in one place you must explain all other places as well.* If $A$ is an algebra, and you want to define an algebra structure on $A^2$, then it's quite natural to define the addition by $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$. It looks like you're doing vector addition, but even if you never heard of vectors, that's how you would define the addition. But for the multiplication, you have some choices to make. E.g., if $A$ is the rationals, then $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac+2bd,ad+bc)$ is one of many possibilities. Vectors are for addition, not multiplication.

Comment: @GerryMyerson To me switching from the real numbers to complex analysis was extremely difficult. I tried to use all the old instruments and finally realized that I do not have any intuition on the complex analysis at all. The suggestion to think of complex numbers as vectors "occasionally", "in some cases" (when exactly when you deal with integrals?) I consider one of the worse misleading practices in complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably one of the reasons the formula is not considered in many courses is because it belongs to a different "world": to the Geometric Algebra.

Let us consider a 4-dimensional space $\{1, e_1, e_2, e_1e_2\}$ with the following multiplication rules:

- $e_1{\cdot}e_1 = e_2{\cdot}e_2 = 1$
- $e_1{\cdot}e_2 = e_1e_2$
- $e_2{\cdot}e_1 = -e_1e_2$

From the rules above:

- $e_1{\cdot}e_1e_2 = e_1{\cdot}e_1{\cdot}e_2= 1{\cdot}e_2 = e_2$
- $e_2{\cdot}e_1e_2 = -(e_1{\cdot}e_2){\cdot}e_2 = -e_1(e_2{\cdot}e_2) = -e_1$
- $e_1e_2{\cdot}e_1e_2 = e_1(e_2{\cdot}e_1)e_2 = -e_1(e_1{\cdot}e_2)e_2 = -(e_1{\cdot}e_1)(e_2{\cdot}e_2) = -1$

Thus, the imaginary unit $i$ of complex numbers corresponds to the element $e_1e_2$ of the 4-space.

The product of 4-vectors in this space is defined as the multiplication of polynomials:

$(a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1)(a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2) = (a_1{\cdot}1{+}b_1{\cdot}e_1{+}c_1{\cdot}e_2{+}d_1{\cdot}e_1e_2)(a_2{\cdot}1{+}b_2{\cdot}e_1{+}c_2{\cdot}e_2{+}d_2{\cdot}e_1e_2)$

Applying the rules above (in column vector form for convenience):

$\begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\\ b_1 \\\ c_1 \\\ d_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_2 \\\ b_2 \\\ c_2 \\\ d_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1a_2 + b_1b_2 + c_1c_2 - d_1d_2 \\\ a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 + d_1c_2 - c_1d_2 \\\ a_1c_2 + a_2c_1 + b_1d_2 - b_2d_1\\\ a_1d_2 + a_2d_1 + b_1c_2 - b_2c_1 \end{pmatrix}$

Using the matrix formula it is easy to check that the subset of elements of the form $z = (x, 0, 0, y)$
is isomorphic to complex numbers:

$zw = (x_1, 0, 0, y_1)(x_2, 0, 0, y_2) = (x_1x_2 - y_1y_2, 0, 0, x_1y_2 + x_2y_1)$,

whereas the product of $2D$ vectors $\overrightarrow{z} = (0, x, y, 0)$
is a map onto the complex numbers:

$\overrightarrow{z}\overrightarrow{w} = (0, x_1, y_1, 0)(0, x_2, y_2, 0) = (x_1x_2 + y_1y_2, 0, 0, x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)$

Comparing the last two expressions one can find the "true" connection between multiplications of vectors and complex numbers:

- $\overrightarrow{z}\overrightarrow{w} = z^*w$
- $zw = \overrightarrow{z^*}\overrightarrow{w}$

where $z,w$ are the "complex", and $\overrightarrow{z}, \overrightarrow{w}$ the corresponding $2D$-vector elements of the 4-space,
and $(a,b,c,d)^* = (a,b,-c,-d)$

Comment: "Let us consider a 4-dimensional space $(1,e_1,e_2,e_1e_2)$." That's not a 4-dimensional space, that's just a 4-element set. Presumably what you mean is the 4-dimensional real vector space with basis $\{1,e_1,e_2,e_1e_2\}$, which you then see as an algebra by defining a multiplication. You freely use various properties of this multiplication (e.g., associativity, distributive law, $1x=x$) without explicitly saying so. But what have you gained by not simply seeing the complex numbers as a 2-dimensional real vector space with basis $\{1,i\}$, and an algebra with multipllication $i^2=-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. I have fixed the basis notation. I have discovered the Geometric Algebra for myself couple days ago. So, I do not "freely use" it. I simply assume the subject is studied well, and if I make a mistake somebody will help me. What I gained from it? The discovery that complex numbers are not vectors. Period. But they co-exist with vectors and connected to them within a single space I have never heard about before.

Comment: "I have fixed the basis notation." You are still listing a basis, and calling it a space. A basis for a vector space isn't a vector space. If Geometric Algebra gives you joy, that's good, and I'm happy for you. I still hold that the reason introductions to complex numbers don't do it your way is that it's more complicated, uses more machinery, than their way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have got an impression that Geometric Algebra is not welcomed here. This is intriguing. Are you saying it is incomplete, or useless, or contains flaws?

Comment: I have nothing to say against Geometric Algebra. All I've tried to do here is to answer your question about why we teach arithmetic of complex numbers the way we do.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. It was an educating discussion to me.